# Separate form fields to "parts"; render part with loop, render part with specific design, render part with loop again

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to render part of the form via a loop in template and a part with specific "design".

```py
# forms.py
class HappyIndexForm(forms.Form):
    pizza_eaten = forms.IntegerField(label="Pizzas eaten")
    # 5 more fields
    minutes_outside = forms.IntegerField(label="Minutes outside")

class TherapyNeededForm(HappyIndexForm):
    had_therapy_before = forms.BooleanField()
    # about 20 more fields

class CanMotivateOthers(HappyIndexForm):
    has_hobbies = forms.BooleanField()
    # about 20 more fields
```

The only purpose of `HappyIndexForm` is to pass the 7 fields to other forms that need to work with the "HappyIndex" (it is a made up example).

I have designed a very nice and complex template for the `HappyIndexForm`fields. The fields of `TherapyNeededForm` exclusive of the `HappyIndexForm`fields I want to simply loop over.

```html
<!-- template.html -->
{% for field in first_ten_fields_therapy_needed %}
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}

{% include happyindexform.html %}

{% for field in second_ten_fields_therapy_needed %}
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

###### Task:

Loop over first ten fields of `TherapyNeededForm`, then display the specific template I wrote for the fields coming from `HappyIndexForm` called 'happyindexform.html', then loop over second ten fields of `TherapyNeededForm`.

###### My problem:

If I loop over the fields and include my 'happyindexform.html' the fields coming from inheritance get displayed twice. I for sure can also write the specific template for all the 20 fields of `TherapyNeededForm` but that is very repetitive and not in any way aligned to DRY.

Note: I am using django's class-based views. That's why I feel using 2 forms would be more stressful than the inheritance approach.

I feel like I am somehow missing how I can devide my form to blocks and ship them to the template separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the `HappyIndexForm` is used as a base [form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#the-django-form-class) for other form classes. Here, you have two other form classes - `TherapyNeededForm` and `CanMotivateOthersForm` - that inherit from `HappyIndexForm`, thereby inheriting its fields.

When you instantiate `TherapyNeededForm` or `CanMotivateOthersForm`, they will have all the fields from `HappyIndexForm` along with their own additional fields.

The goal would be therefore to separate out the fields inherited from `HappyIndexForm` from the rest of the fields in `TherapyNeededForm` and `CanMotivateOthersForm`, which allows you to treat them differently in your templates.

In Django, form fields are stored in a dictionary-like object, which ensures that the fields are always iterated over in the order (by default) they were defined in the form class (see "[Notes on field ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#notes-on-field-ordering)").
You could take advantage of this to separate the fields into three parts:

- the first 10,
- the inherited fields from `HappyIndexForm`,
- and the remaining fields.

To do this, you can use Python's built-in `itertools` library, specifically the []`islice` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), which returns an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable.

In your view, you can slice the fields into two parts, the first ten and the remaining fields.
Then, in the template, you can include the 'happyindexform.html' after the first loop.

---

However, the key here is to remember that Django form fields need to be accessed in a **[bound state]([https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms%5D)** in order to be rendered properly in a template.

When you iterate over a form object directly, you get bound fields, which are the field objects bound to the form and its data. These bound fields can be directly included in templates, and Django will render the appropriate HTML.

That means a code like this one would be incorrect:

```py
// Incorrect
first_ten_fields = list(islice(form, 10))
remaining_fields = list(islice(form, 10, None))
```

This is incorrect, because slicing the form object gives us the fields themselves, not the bound fields, which are needed for rendering.

You need first to get a list of all field names, and then to slice this list of names:

```py
// Correct
all_fields = list(form.fields.keys())
first_ten_fields = list(islice(all_fields, 10))
second_ten_fields = list(islice(all_fields, 10, None))
```

And you need to be careful with the template themselves:

```html
<!-- Incorrect -->
{% for field in first_ten_fields %}
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

That does not work because `field` is not a bound field, it's just the field itself: you need to use the field names (`form[field_name]`) to access the corresponding bound fields:

```html
<!-- Correct -->
{% for field_name in first_ten_fields %}
{{ form[field_name] }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

The code would be:

```py
from itertools import islice

class TherapyNeededView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = TherapyNeededForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = context['form']

        # Get all field names
        all_fields = list(form.fields.keys())

        # Get the first 10 field names
        first_ten_fields = list(islice(all_fields, 10))

        # Get the field names inherited from HappyIndexForm
        happy_index_fields = [name for name in all_fields if name in HappyIndexForm.base_fields]

        # Get the remaining field names
        remaining_fields = list(islice(all_fields, len(happy_index_fields) + len(first_ten_fields), None))

        # Update the context
        context.update({
            'first_ten_fields_therapy_needed': first_ten_fields,
            'happy_index_fields': happy_index_fields,
            'second_ten_fields_therapy_needed': remaining_fields,
        })

        return context
```

In your template, you can use these new variables:

```html
<!-- template.html -->
{% for field_name in first_ten_fields_therapy_needed %}
{{ form[field_name] }}
{% endfor %}

{% include happyindexform.html %}

{% for field_name in second_ten_fields_therapy_needed %}
{{ form[field_name] }}
{% endfor %}
```

And in your '`happyindexform.html`', you can loop over the fields:

```html
<!-- happyindexform.html -->
{% for field_name in happy_index_fields %}
{{ form[field_name] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This way, the fields from the `HappyIndexForm` will only be displayed once.

---

The line in the view:

```py
happy_index_fields = [name for name in all_fields if name in HappyIndexForm.base_fields]
```

This line is going through the names of the fields of the form in the view (either `TherapyNeededForm` or `CanMotivateOthersForm`), and picking out the ones that are part of `HappyIndexForm`.
These field names are then passed to the template separately from the other field names.

In the template, we use these names to access the corresponding bound fields from the form. Django will then render these bound fields correctly.

This approach allows you to use your special template for the `HappyIndexForm` fields while avoiding the issue of displaying these fields twice.

Comment: This is a great answer, really clear and concise!

Comment: Coming from you (an actual Django specialist) that means a lot, thank you.

Comment: I appreciate your support and agree, the answer reads nicely. I am still struggling though, because the fields are not getting rendered anymore. Before it rendered a nice inputfield and stuff, now it just displays: `<django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x7faca8552860>`.

Comment: @Tarquinius I will have a look as soon as I am back. I am on my phone at the moment. I thought it was working since the answer was accepted.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid that was me clicking a bit too fast.

Comment: Ok, don't worry - I got a working solution. The problem with your approach is that only [`BoundField`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField) can be rendered. I am going to edit your response some time soon, by Sunday the latest. Thanks!

Comment: @Tarquinius I have edited extensively the answer to work with bound field instead of directly the fields themselves. I have updated the python code for the view, and the HTML template: let me know if that is working better.